# What is the extra line showing up in my simple Bokeh chart?

Tags: python, bokeh

Very simple line chart I'm trying to do. I'm getting some additional line showing with the chart. My code is quite simple:

```
p = figure(width=1000, height=400, x_axis_type='datetime', title='ohlcv', tools='box_zoom')
p.line(df.timestamp, df.open, line_color='green')
show(p)
```

Here is the result:

[image: green, scraggly, descending line]

The dataframe is very basic, so I can't imagine it's some anomaly with the data. Can someone please help me understand what this is and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have the data nor the code so it's a bit difficult to help, but I guess the problem is that in your data, the x axis values are not ordered, hence you are seeing those lines which are just linking points in your data. You should order the points your dataframe by the timestamp.

Next time, try to come up with a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: omg thank you that worked. I spent 2 hours trying everything i could before asking here. I feel so stupid for not realising that. Wasn't sure how to post the data side of it, but next time will aim to post an abridged version. Thank you again!

Comment: Well you don't need to post all the data. You can try to come up with a minimalistic toy example that still reproduces your problem. It's hard and takes time, but generally, from my experience, it will help you understand where the problem comes from on your own.